# Android. make a system app that run another app

Tags: java, android

im making a `app` that observes for some apps that are runing or not and execute it if dont

i dont know how to oberserve other apps processes and how to start another app that wasnt maked by me.

all that i got for now is run it as system `service`.

another possibility is create a self app that restart it own when it `crashes` or be `closed`.

there is any way to do it ?
My cell is not `rooted`

Answer (score 0):

For your question, you can learn the application sandbox.
https://source.android.com/security/app-sandbox

When the developer makes an application, they can define their intent filter and tt is some way to let another application invoke it.

You can uncompress .apk from another application and find out the file AndroidManifest.xml. And then you can try it.

But you can just control the part of door they open to you.